# Developer story bug - 'save as pdf' no email shown

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, developer-story

When I save the developer story as a PDF, there is no email in the top right like there used to be.

I checked my preferences page and anywhere else I could think of to input an email and made sure they were all populated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have pushed a fix, can you verify if your email now shows up on the PDF?

For reference, the issue was a side effect of when we switched from Careers/CV to Jobs/Developer Story.

The PDF Export will now use either the email address under *Jobs Emails* (this field is only visible for a few users, you won't see it) or the one for *Q&A Emails*, which is now becoming the main, verified Email address of an account.

Please check the [Preferences Page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) to set or change the email address.

Comment: This works! Makes sense. Thanks for fixing it.