# Make it easier to set email for Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, profile-page, developer-story

When exporting my Developer Story to PDF, an email address prints in the upper right. It took considerable time to find how to change this.

It appears to be set via https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current (not the first entry, but below under **Jobs Emails**).

However this is not at all obvious from the Developer Story or Edit Profile tabs. There is another private email listed at the bottom of Edit your profile ( `/users/edit/#` ).

Could this be clarified somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an [earlier issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341769/developer-story-bug-save-as-pdf-no-email-shown/341899#341899) that is now resolved, but the main problem is that there are basically three different email addresses in play.

There's an ongoing project to consolidate all email logic and avoid the confusion of having email addresses in several places. Once that is all in place, those screens will be revamped.